# I am trying to write this sql statement and put it in c# datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

```
@" select distinct  a.ComplaintNum as OFFENSE#,a.CaseType as CaseType,a.ResolutionNum as ResolutionNum,a.LienDate as LIENDATE, a.LienRelBook as BOOK#, a.LienRelPage as PAGE#,c.Code as LienStatus, b.CaseId
                     , sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 29 THEN b.UnitCost END) AS AdminFee
                      , sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 1 THEN b.UnitCost END) AS SubFee
                      , sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 15 THEN b.UnitCost END) AS ContFee
                          ,sum (case when b.FeeType IN (1, 29) then b.UnitCost END) as TotalAdminCost                                                 

                    ,d.AmtDue as AmountDue, d.AmtPaid as AmountPaid



                from 
               CE_CaseMaster a
                inner join CE_CaseFee b on a.id= b.CaseId
                inner join CE_eLienStatus c on a.LienStatus =c.id
                inner join CE_LienRelDetails d on a.OffenceNum=d.OffenceNum

                GROUP BY a.ComplaintNum,a.ResolutionNum,b.CaseId,a.LienDate,a.LienRelBook,a.LienRelPage,a.CaseType,c.Code,d.AmtDue,d.AmtPaid

                     Where a.ComplaintNum like '" + txtOffenseNumber.Text + "%'"
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I am getting an error near the where statement

Comment: what does the error say.. come on now.. we are not mind readers here.

Comment: `an error` The solution to your problem is to fix the error. What I mean is, be more specific.

Comment: you need to tell us the error and give us some code around such as how you are executing the statement....

Comment: are you getting an `Aggregate` error .. if so then you need to include the columns in the where clause that you have defined in your select statement

Comment: Try to take some time and read how to ask a question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'

Comment: You may also use SQL FIDDLE for your SQL Query and see what's wrong from there: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: here is my suggestion personally I would convert that code into a stored procedure and make it easier to read.. also error in where clause could mean a number of things like column does not exist could be the Alias columns that you are using could be expected in the where clause vs the literal name of the actual column.. also wrap and special characters for names in `[ ]` or in single quotes.. and once you change the order of the GROUP BY and WHERE CLAUSE.. make sure you don't get any aggreate errors..

Comment: I wanted to know how to rewrite the where and group by syntax so I don't get the syntax error when I put the where after group by and if I put the group by at the end it does not block invalid expression error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY` comes after `WHERE` clause

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `Where a.ComplaintNum like '" + txtOffenseNumber.Text + "%'"` should be replaced with sql-parameters.